# Implement "cloud saving" in C#

Tags: c#, php, security, ftp

I have a game I've been working on that I want to do a sort of "cloud saving" with. My issue is securely uploading save files so that we don't expose our website or FTP server. Right now, I'm using FTP with a severely restricted account that has access to /saves, but it also has access to each user's save directory. Malicious destruction of save data was solved with some clever design, and it's not what I'm worried about. I am worried about someone getting ahold of the FTP account I use to login (wouldn't be too hard, because it has to be stored in code) and using it to make multiple connections and upload massive files. I don't want to place an upload restriction on the account, because all of my users have to use the same account for uploading, and I don't want legitimate users running into issues. However, this still presents an issue. Users have a WordPress username and password they use to launch the game, and the launcher validates permissions through WordPress. Ideally, when people buy the game I'd like to create a directory for them, as well as a username and password and upload limit of probably 10MB/day, but I doubt our hosting service provides this so I'm looking at alternate methods.

tl;dr How do I restrict users of my game into a specific directory with an upload limit, potentially without using FTP? I tried to do uploading with PHP before, but it's generally frowned upon when a remote PHP script tries to access files on a user's machine without any sort of FORM element. I guess it might work if I could initiate some sort of upload from the client... I'd still have to find a way to prevent malicious uploads, though.
Any ideas, anyone? This is something I'd really like to do, and to do it I need to make it secure against attacks.
Thanks!

Comment: I feel like your tl;dr needs a tl;dr also I have concerns with how clever the security is if everyone shares the same credentials.

Comment: @Jason Only the uploading shares credentials, the encryption of the save data uses the user's (salted) password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this the kind of problem that web service created to solve? You can create a web service, integrate it with your user database, so your game would call the service to upload and download the data with authentication token from Wordpress. It won't stop anyone from DDOSing your webservice, but at least no risk for leaked password. Do note, according to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22985/Upload-Any-File-Type-through-a-Web-Service), there's a hard limit to the uploaded data at 4MB. Of course you can simply split the file before sending them and handle the joining at the server.

Comment: In ASP.Net, the 4MB limit is just a default that can be easily changed.

Comment: I'm thinking this will work perfectly. My save files are under 1MB, so that's not an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Martheen Actually, can you use ASP.NET on an Apache server?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you're using ASP.NET from the C# tag. It's possible, http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET#ASP.NET_hosting_with_Apache but I'll just create a webservice in PHP, since one you follow a convention, it's callable by any language anyway.